# iOS Webview in React-Native - Quota exceded

Tags: ios, react-native, webview, cacheapi

I have a react-native app that uses a webview. This loads a website that is using the Cache API and an indexed db (w/Dexie) to save some data.
If I run this site on the browser normally and try to save some content for offline use and exceed the 1GB limit I get a prompt to ask if the user allows the app to use more space (check picture).
[image: aumentar el tamano]

The problem is when I open the react-native app with the webview to the same website and try to save data for offline use. I'm getting an "Cache API operation failed: Quota exceeded" error. When we use the webview to load the website there are no prompt to ask for permission to use more storage. Is there a way to increase the available space on webview or to show up the authorization dialog as we have for PWA?

- Test device: iphone 13 ios 15.3.1
- react-native-webview: 11.13.0

  (https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview)